# How to do backend coding of HTML element in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

Hi after creating a button in HTML in Visual studio, how can i do its backend c# coding? Normally while using webforms double click will open coding class but how to acheive this in Visual studio for HTML element?

Comment: You have to use asp.net or asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the MVC pattern. To be more familiar with, you can read this documentation https://www.asp.net/mvc.

Few words about MVC pattern:

> ## Define MVC in layman’s terms
>
> Remember you’re technically minded and close to the code. MVC to you
> is as clear as day, but saying to the business ‘Model, View,
> Contoller’ could give them the impression that you are suffering from
> some form tourette syndrome. MVC won’t mean much to the business even
> after you define them in relation to the code. To get the business to
> understand why this is the answer and least of all what it is, can be
> more of a task than expected in my experience. Even some fellow
> developers have difficulty understanding this on occasion.
>
> To get the listener to understand what MVC is and why it works what I
> have tried in the pass is to apply MVC to a different industries where
> the listeners have had more involvement. An example that has worked
> for me in the past in a comparison to the property or even the
> vehicles. Most people have had dealing’s with builders, carpenters,
> plumbers, electricians or have watched the flood of property shows on
> the TV. This experience is a good platform to use and to explain why
> separation such as MVC works. I know you’re probably thinking that
> won’t work as it’s not the same as in software, but remember you’re
> not trying to train the business to become developers or have an in
> depth understanding of MVC, simply explaining to them that separation
> in production is required and that’s what an MVC structure offers.
>
> To give an example of how you could describe this I have very briefly
> explained how separation works in property. Keep in mind this is
> focused on using the system not developing which could be a completely
> different angle of explanation.
>
> ### View
>
> **The view in MVC is the presentation layer.** This is what the end user
> of a product will see and interact with. A system can have multiple
> views of all different types ranging from command line output to
> rendered HTML. The view doesn’t consist of business logic in most
> clear designs. The interface is fit for purpose and is the area of
> interaction. Therefore you could simply output HTML for consumers to
> interact with or output SOAP/XML for businesses to interact with. Both
> use the same business logic behind the system otherwise known as the
> models and controllers.
>
> In the world of property you could think of the view as the interior
> of a property or the outer layer of a property that the inhabitants
> interact with. The interior can be customised for purpose and the same
> property can have many different types of tenants. For example a
> property of a particular design could contain residential dwellings.
> The same internal space could easily be used as office space, where
> although in the same property has a different purpose. However the
> property structure is the same. Therefore the environment in which the
> users interact does not interfere with the structure of the building.
>
> ### Controllers
>
> **The controller is where the magic happens and defines the business
> application logic.** This could be where the user has sent a response
> from the view, then this response is used to process the internal
> workings of the request and processes the response back to the user.
> Taking a typical response where a user has requested to buy a book.
> The controller has the user id, payment details, shipping address and
> item choice. These elements are then processed through the business
> logic to complete a purchase. The data is passed through the system
> into the model layer and eventually after the entire request satisfies
> the business definitions, the order is constructed and the user
> receives their item.
>
> If we compare this to a property, we could compare the ordering of a
> book online to turning on a light switch. A tenant will flick the
> switch to on just like ordering a book. The switch itself is an
> element in the view layer which sends the request to the controller
> just like clicking a checkout button on a web site. The business logic
> in this case is what the electrician installed and are embedded within
> the property designs. The switch is flicked, which completes the
> circuit. Electricity runs through all the wires including the fuse box
> straight through to the light bulb. Just like the user receiving a
> book, in this case the tenant receives light. The whole process behind
> the scenes involving the electricity cabling is not visible to the the
> tenant. They simply interact with the switch within the space and from
> there the controller handles the request.
>
> ### Models
>
> **The models in MVC are the bottom most layer and handle the core logic
> of the system.** In most cases this could be seen as the layer that
> interacts with the data source. In systems using MVC, the controller
> will pass information to the model in order to store and retrieve
> data. Following on from the example above controller definition, this
> is where the order details are stored. Additional data such as stock
> levels, physical location of product of the book amongst many things
> are all stored here. If that was the last book in stock ordered, the
> next request for this item may check if it’s available and disallow
> the order as the item is no longer available.
>
> Sticking with out example of turning on a light switch, this level in
> our structure could be the electricity supply. When the tenant flicks
> the switch, the internal circuit must request electricity to power the
> request which is similar when the user requested data from the
> database, as in data is needed to process a request. If the dwelling
> isn’t connected to an electric supply, it cannot complete the process.
> Business benefits from using MVC
>
> After you get the message across explaining what MVC is, you will then
> have to see what benefits can be obtained from it. I’m not going to go
> into a huge amount of detail here are I’m sure you can apply benefits
> more accurately which are directly related to you actual situation. To
> list just some of the common benefits of an MVC based system here are
> a few examples:
>
> - Different skill levels can work on different system levels. For example designers can work on the interface (View) with very little
>   development knowledge and developers can work on the business logic
>   (Controller) with very little concern for the design level. Then they
>   simply integrate together on completion.
> - As a result of the above separation projects can be managed easier and quicker. The designer can start the interfaces before the
>   developer and vice versa. This development process can be parallel as
>   opposed to being sequential therefore reducing development time.
> - Easy to have multiple view types using the same business logic.
> - Clear route through the system. You clearly know where there different levels of the system are. With a clear route of the system,
>   logic can be shared and improved. This has added security benefits as
>   you clearly know the permitted route from the data to the user and can
>   have clear security checks along the route.
> - Each layer is responsible for itself. (Relates to point 1) This means that you can have clean file structure which can be maintained
>   and managed much easier and quicker than a tightly couple system where
>   you may have lots of duplicate logic.
> - Having a clear structure means development will be more transparent which should result in reduced development time,
>   maintenance problems and release cycles if applied properly.

Source: http://www.strongandagile.co.uk/index.php/a-really-simple-explanation-of-mvc/

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without MVC pattern.

Comment: I'm going to create another answer, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is keep programming using WebForms, for that, you have to choose the right application:

[image]